# Test `window.onerror` call with vitest and React

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, jsdom, vitest

I am unable to reach `window.onerror` in React tests with vitest, jsdom, and React Testing Library when throwing inside an event handler. The same test passes in Jest.

Goal: Assert that `window.onerror` is called when an error is thrown in an event handler (e.g., `onClick`). It seems that vitest with jsdom doesn't propagate JS errors to `window.onerror`?

### Vitest code

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import ReactTestUtils from "react-dom/test-utils";
import { vi, it, expect } from "vitest";
import React from "react";

it("window.onerror is called on unhandled error in event handler", async () => {
  const spy = vi.spyOn(console, "error");
  spy.mockImplementation(() => undefined);

  const caught = vi.fn();
  const App = () => {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          throw new Error("ahhhh");
        }}
      >
        Error
      </button>
    );
  };

  class Tracker extends React.Component<any, any> {
    componentDidMount() {
      window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
        caught();
        return true;
      };
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }

  render(
    <Tracker>
      <App />
    </Tracker>
  );

  expect(caught).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  const button = await screen.findByText("Error");

  try {
    // using ReactTestUtils here since it allows me to catch the error
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(button);
  } catch (e) {
    // do nothing
  }

  expect(caught).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

#### Dependencies

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"

    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "jsdom": "^23.0.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.4",
    "vitest": "^0.34.6"
```

The test fails with the following error message:

```bash
 FAIL  index.test.tsx > window.onerror is called on unhandled error in event handler
AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called 1 times, but got 0 times
 ❯ index.test.tsx:52:18
     50|   }
     51| 
     52|   expect(caught).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
       |                  ^
     53| });
     54|
```

The same test passes with Jest (Jest code below). Note that the code is very much the same. I only replaced `jest` with `vi`.

### Jest code

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import ReactTestUtils from "react-dom/test-utils";
import { jest, it, expect } from "@jest/globals";
import React from "react";

it("window.onerror is called on unhandled error in event handler", async () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(console, "error");
  spy.mockImplementation(() => undefined);

  const caught = jest.fn();
  const App = () => {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          throw new Error("ahhhh");
        }}
      >
        Error
      </button>
    );
  };

  class Tracker extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      window.onerror = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
        caught();
        return true;
      };
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }

  render(
    <Tracker>
      <App />
    </Tracker>
  );

  expect(caught).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  const button = await screen.findByText("Error");

  try {
    // using ReactTestUtils here since it allows me to catch the error
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(button);
  } catch (e) {
    // do nothing
  }

  expect(caught).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

#### Dependencies

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"

    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0"
```

Looking for ways to work around this. Any way I can reach `window.onerror` in vitest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the vitest test by replacing `window.onerror =` with `window.addEventListener('error', ...)`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
    caught();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your vitest setup, you can manually mock window.onerror before the test and then assert whether it was called:

```
it("window.onerror is called on unhandled error in event handler", async () => {
  // ... other setup ...

  // Mock window.onerror
  const originalOnError = window.onerror;
  window.onerror = vi.fn();

  // ... rendering and event simulation ...

  // Check if window.onerror was called
  expect(window.onerror).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  // Restore original window.onerror
  window.onerror = originalOnError;
});
```

Create an error boundary component and use it to capture errors:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // You can log the error here
    this.props.onError();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // Render fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

it("error boundary catches error", async () => {
  const onError = vi.fn();

  render(
    <ErrorBoundary onError={onError}>
      <App />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );

  // ... simulate the click ...

  expect(onError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

If you have control over the error-throwing logic, you can dispatch a custom event and listen for that in your tests:

```
// Inside your component
const handleClick = () => {
  try {
    throw new Error("ahhhh");
  } catch (e) {
    const event = new CustomEvent("customError", { detail: e });
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
};

// In your test
window.addEventListener("customError", caught);

// ... simulate the click ...

expect(caught).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I clarified my question, I am specifically trying to reach onerror when throwing in an event handler in React. Does `expect(window.onerror).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` work for you when throwing in `onClick`?